# Python/Gensim - What is the meaning of syn0 and syn0norm?

Tags: python, deep-learning, nlp, gensim, word-embedding

I know that in *gensims* *`KeyedVectors`-model*, one can access the embedding matrix by the attribute `model.syn0`. There is also a `syn0norm`, which doesn't seem to work for the *glove* model I recently loaded. I think I also have seen `syn1` somewhere previously.

I haven't found a doc-string for this and I'm just wondering what's the logic behind this?

So if `syn0` is the embedding matrix, what is `syn0norm`? What would then `syn1` be and generally, what does `syn` stand for?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These names were inherited from the original Google `word2vec.c` implementation, upon which the `gensim` `Word2Vec` class was based. (I believe `syn0` only exists in recent versions for backward-compatbility.)

The `syn0` array essentially holds raw word-vectors. From the perspective of the neural-network used to train word-vectors, these vectors are a 'projection layer' that can convert a one-hot encoding of a word into a dense embedding-vector of the right dimensionality.

Similarity operations tend to be done on the *unit-normalized* versions of the word-vectors. That is, vectors that have all been scaled to have a magnitude of 1.0. (This makes the cosine-similarity calculation easier.) The `syn0norm` array is filled with these unit-normalized vectors, the first time they're needed.

This `syn0norm` will be empty until either you do an operation (like `most_similar()`) that requires it, or you explicitly do an `init_sims()` call. If you explicitly do an `init_sims(replace=True)` call, you'll actually clobber the raw vectors, in-place, with the unit-normed vectors. This saves the memory that storing both vectors for every word would otherwise require. (However, some word-vector uses may still be interested in the original raw vectors of varying magnitudes, so only do this when you're sure `most_similar()` cosine-similarity operations are all you'll need.)

The `syn1` (or `syn1neg` in the more common case of negative-sampling training) properties, when they exist on a full model (and not for a plain `KeyedVectors` object of only word-vectors), are the model neural network's internal 'hidden' weights leading to the output nodes. They're needed during model training, but not a part of the typical word-vectors collected after training.

I believe the `syn` prefix is just a convention from neural-network variable-naming, likely derived from 'synapse'.

Comment: @gojomo When flattening my word2vec model, I was using vecotrs = model.wv.syn0 and I am getting a deprecation warning.  Is there a new way to extract the vector matrix?

Comment: @TylerRussell What was the text of the deprecation warning?

Comment: DeprecationWarning: Call to deprecated `syn0` (Attribute will be removed in 4.0.0, use self.vectors instead).  I played around with my IDE and found model.wv.vectors and have been assuming that's what the message wanted me to use.  Is that wrong?

Comment: Yes, that message means you should use `.vectors` instead of `.syn0`.